# Socket.io showing question mark characters in log

Tags: node.js, encoding, socket.io

It seems like communication from a specific client generates these question mark characeters. Normally these are a sign of bad encoding, but it doesn't seem as if this is something I have control over.

Should I be concerned? Is there something wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is likely there binary data is being passed in the packet and the terminal simply cannot escape it. It can throw out junk like that if there are non-printable characters.